# Need help understanding inverting softmax from Michael Nielsen's book

Tags: self-study, softmax

I have a hard time understanding a softmax problem from the book:

> Inverting the softmax layer Suppose we have a neural network with a softmax output layer
> and the > activations $a^L_j$ are known. Show that
> the corresponding weighted inputs have the form $z^L_j = \ln a^L_j + C$
> for some constant $C$ that is independent of $j$.

Here is how I've approached: $a^L_j= \exp(z^L_j) / \sum(\exp(z^L_k))$. Take the log of both sides, $\ln(a^L_j) = z^L_j - \ln(\sum(\exp(z^L_k)))$. Then, $z^L_j = \ln(a^L_j) + \ln(\sum(\exp(z^L_k)))$ The problem happens here. Why we're allowed to substitute $\ln(\sum(\exp(z^L_k)))$ for $C$ when it has $z^L_j$ in it? Everyone from my research says $C$ is independent of $j$ so it can be $C$. But, doesn't that mean we have to extract $e^L_j$ out of $\ln(\sum(\exp(z^L_k)))$?

Can you please give me a insight into this problem?

Comment: Hi, please take a moment to fix your LaTeX. Also, because this is a textbook problem, please tag as [tag:self-study].

Comment: Thank you for the modification, Arya. I updated the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of which $j$ you’re currently considering, the log-sum-exp term you’ve written out (the log–normalizing constant)  is the same. That’s the independence that this textbook problem asks about. Rather than pulling the $j$ out, show that it doesn’t matter which $j$ you put in.

Comment: Sorry I'm still not with you, why we're not considering the fact that C would increase as z^L_j increases? What makes every variable in the equation fixed values so that we care about only index?

Comment: Of course C would change if any of the $z^L_j$s changes. But in terms of the normalizing constant for a _particular_ set of $z$s, the symmetry in the equation makes the $C$ the same for all of them.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!